# How to access data from a state in functional components in your JSX

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am learning RN and have the following code that fetches a single post from an API, I use useState hook to set my post once it has fully fetched and set it to post. How do I now access the data in this post from my JSX? (eg post.title, post.id) since I can't use Flatlist data prop for my case. Also any corrections on my code implementation is welcome

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import moment from "moment";

const SinglePostScreen = props => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [post, setPost] = useState();

  const fetchSinglePost = async () => {
    let post_id = props.navigation.getParam("post_id");
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://kriss.io/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&include=${post_id}`
    );
    const post = await response.json();
    setPost(post);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      fetchSinglePost();
    }),
    [setPost]
  );

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is a post of id {post.id}</Text>
I want to access the data from here but how do i pass it to here. I cant use the Flatlist 
data property
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default SinglePostScreen;
```

Comment: Why can't you just `{post.title}` in your JSX? Or perhaps it's not clear what problem you are having. Can you describe your problem more clearly?

Comment: When I try {post.id} or {post.title} I get nothing displayed so am wondering if I am having access in the first place to the post state. But when I try {post} I get the "Objects are not valid react child"

Comment: I managed to figure out where the problem is because my data was being fetched. The post had an index and calling it as {post[0].title} finally displayed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api returns an array, so you should add logic to read from an array when using your 'post' variable.

Another thing, useEffect expects a variable on the second argument, but it's used to define when it updates (when the variables passed change, it gets executed). If you pass the setPost variable, useEffect will only get called at the first render, and whenever you change this variable (which you cant because it's a function defined with const). If you want for it to be called only once, just pass an empty array.

Comment: I managed to figure it out that I needed to used index to access the post so post[0].title managed to work. Am still getting to understand useEffect so thanks for the additional information